# Generate Large Upward Pointing Triangle From Existing Code Using SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, path

I am using the following code from [Tympanus](http://tympanus.net/Development/SectionSeparators/) to generate a big downward pointing triangle. What I am trying to do is use the same technique to generate a big upward pointing triangle, basic the inverse. Does any one know how to tweak this code to accomplish that?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Best Regards...

```css
svg#bigTriangleColor {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.container svg {
    display: block;
}
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bigTriangleColor path {
    fill: #3498db;
    stroke: #3498db;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg id="bigTriangleColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do that understanding the [line commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) in an SVG path.

What we have here:

```
<path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z"></path>
```

Says:

> Move to (0,0), make a line going to (50,100), make another line going to (100,0), close the path.

So, to invert the triangle, you just need:

```
<path d="M0 100 L50 0 L100 100 Z"></path>
```

Which basicaly says:

> Move to (0,100), make a line going to (50,0), make another line going to (100,100), close the path.

Check the demo:

```css
svg#bigTriangleColor {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.container svg {
    display: block;
}
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bigTriangleColor path {
    fill: #3498db;
    stroke: #3498db;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg id="bigTriangleColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="M0 100 L50 2 L100 100 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Voting this one up as it addressed goal by manipulating the SVG path. Thank for including some instructions on how drawing the shape works!

Answer (score 1):

You could just draw it upside down using a transform.

- translate moves it down (as it's now going to be drawn from the bottom to the top rather than top to bottom.
- scale inverts it in the y direction

```css
svg#bigTriangleColor {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.container svg {
    display: block;
}
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bigTriangleColor path {
    fill: #3498db;
    stroke: #3498db;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg id="bigTriangleColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path transform="translate(0, 102) scale(1, -1)" d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: This was an excellent work-around. I thank you for reminding me of this option!