# Generate Inner Shadow Effect On An SVG "Path" Element / Two Sides Of A Triangle

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, path

I am using an SVG/Path to generate a large upward pointing triangle...see the related link below for some background info.

[Background Info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391334/generate-large-upward-pointing-triangle-from-existing-code-using-svg)

What I am trying to do is add an inset, blurred shadow (simiar to box-shadow) on two sides of the triangle (top-left and top-right), but not the base of the triangle. Also trying to taper the shadow so that it does not touch the base of the triangle. The following link is screenshot with a rough, but not exact, idea of what I am looking to do.

[Shadow Example](http://screencast.com/t/SWswEAerd)

Here is the code I have so far:

```css
svg#bigTriangleColor {
    pointer-events: none; background: red;
}
.container svg {
    display: block;
}
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#bigTriangleColor path {
    fill: #EEEEEE;
    stroke: #EEEEEE;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```

```html
<svg id="bigTriangleColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path d="M0 100 L50 2 L100 100 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Thanks in advance, any help is greatly apprecizted...

Answer (score 0):

Add a grey shape behind the triangle to represent the shadow. Then blur it.

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 600 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <polygon points="0,0, 600,0, 600,80, 300,20, 0,80" fill="#999" filter="url(#blur)"/>
  <polygon points="0,0, 600,0, 600,65, 300,20, 0,65" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this contribution...I think this is a great start. However there is one thing that is tripping me up still. I am looking for this shape to be 100% of the viewpoint width and flexible/mobile-responsive, like the example. Is there a way to accomplish that with your code snippet? Any help is greatly appreciated.